# Chrome Extension: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm not sure how the DOM loads for chrome extensions.. I put my script (background.js) under all the html elements but the "cannot set property of null" error still gets thrown.

Here's the manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "notifications", "tabs"]
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<body>
    <div class = "visual">
      <img src = "images/drillserg_default.png" width="80px">
    </div>
    <div class = "visual">
      <p id = "dialogue">"halp..."</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "visual">
      <h2 id = "timer">00:00<p>
    </div>
    <script src = background.js></script>
</body>
```

Here's where .innerHTML comes in on my script (background.js):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   startTimer();
});

function startTimer()
{
  alert("?");
  window.onload = document.getElementById("dialogue").innerHTML = "YOU BETTER WATCH YOURSELF";
  timerOn = false;
}
```

The weird thing is that I removed the ' script src = "background.js" ' completely from the html file and all that changed was that the console.log() calls from my script stopped showing up in the console; background.js seems to run even without the script inclusion on the html. Could it be that the background script always gets loaded before my extension elements do? Would there be any work-around for this? I just want to change the text on my extension...

Thanks for reading the wall of text!

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do, please explain that further what you'd like to happen.

Comment: I want to make the text on my (popup) chrome extension change when startTimer() (see what I pasted from my background.js) gets called, but it keeps throwing the "cannot set property of null" error.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what your problem might be.
Before you continue developing your chrome extension, I have a few tips though.
The chrome extension docs are really helpful, and I suggest you read it and make sure you understand. When I started making extension I skipped that part and it took me a long time with a lot of anger until I figured the basics out.
For your problem however, my guess is that you haven't declared `backround.js` in your `web_accessible_resources`. Just add this to your manifest:

`"web_accessible_resources": ["background.js"],`

Also, you should note that:
`"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},` is not the same as the script for your popup. The background.js script will start running whenever your users browser opens, regardless of wheter or not the user has presses your browser action. Read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

So, if it was unclear. The reason why your `#dialogue` element is undefined is because the script was running without the context of your html page.